# urlrewritefilter tuckey configuration for tomcat 7.0.64

Tags: tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I'm trying to configure urlrewritefilter 4.0.3 but I'm not sure to understand instructions and setting it in the correct way.
I'm using apache-tomcat-7.0.64 installed under /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.64/ and with the following configuration:

Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.64
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.64
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.64/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /opt/jdk1.7.0_80/jre
Using CLASSPATH:      /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.64/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.64/bin/tomcat-juli.jar

I have set the configuration as follow:

```
urlrewritefilter-4.0.3.jar  under folder /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.64/lib
web.xml and urlrewrite.xml files under /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.64/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF
configuration for these files are:
    web.xml content ini  
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <!--
     Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
      contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
      this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
      The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
      (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
      the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

      Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
      distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
      WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
      See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
      limitations under the License.
    -->

    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
      version="3.0"
      metadata-complete="true">

        <filter>
            <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>

            <!-- set the amount of seconds the conf file will be checked for reload
            can be a valid integer (0 denotes check every time,
            empty/not set denotes no reload check) -->
            <init-param>
            <param-name>confReloadCheckInterval</param-name>
            <param-value>0</param-value>
            </init-param>
        </filter>

        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
            <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        </filter-mapping> 

    </web-app>
    web.xml content end     
    ******************************
    urlrewrite.xml content ini 
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <!DOCTYPE urlrewrite
    PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite3.0.dtd">

    <!--
    UrlRewriteFilter from http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/ proyect
    -->
    <urlrewrite>
        <rule>
            <name>redirect</name>
            <condition name="host" operator="notequal">^www.tucarne.com</condition>
            <from>^/(.*)</from>
            <to type="permanent-redirect" last="true">http://www.tucarne.com/$1</to>
        </rule>
    </urlrewrite>

    urlrewrite.xml content end
```

---

As I and getting from manual and FAQs web and urlrewrite files are setted in the correct path and with the correct containt but it doesn't work. I don't know why is wrong.

Could  you help me at this point?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make attention that ROOT web application doesn't serve other web applications' requests. E.g. if you deploy webapplication WEBAPP1 then URL `[protocol]://[hostname]:[port]/WEBAPP1/somepage.html` will not be served by ROOT web application.

It will be served by web application WEBAPP1.

If you configure Turkey filter in ROOT web application then it will process only requests to ROOT web application (the context path is a zero-length string; which is `[protocol]://[hostname]:[port]/` or `[protocol]://[hostname]:[port]/?somearg=value`).